# Calendar usage limits exceeded but not exceeding any quotas

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am using the spatie/google-calendar package in PHP with a service account for a HubSpot integration and our endpoint is returning

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded",
    "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
 }
}
```

All our quotas are still unmet (under the limit). All emails are internal (same domain). I hit the same endpoint locally when the error happens in prod with the same service account creds that prod uses and it works.

here's the code that creates the invite (keep in mind the environment is not local):

```
try
{
    //google
    $self = CrmPerson::where('email',config('hubspot.email.toAddress'))->first();
    if($environment === 'local')
    {
        $event = new Event;
        $event->name = $newTask->subject;
        $event->startDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i A', $request->appointment_date . " " . $request->appointment_time, 'America/New_York');
        $event->endDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i A', $request->appointment_date . " " . $request->appointment_time, 'America/New_York')->addHour()->addMinutes(30);
        $event->addAttendee([ 'email' => $self->email,'name' => $self->nameFirst . ' '. $self->nameLast]);
    }
    else
    {
        $event = new Event;
        $event->name = $newTask->subject;
        $event->startDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i A', $request->appointment_date . " " . $request->appointment_time, 'America/New_York');
        $event->endDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i A', $request->appointment_date . " " . $request->appointment_time, 'America/New_York')->addHour()->addMinutes(30);
        $event->addAttendee([ 'email' => $sm->email]);
        $event->addAttendee(['email' => $ct->email]);
        $event->addAttendee(['email' => $scPerson->email]);
        $event->addAttendee(['email' => $dealPerson->email]);
    }
    $event->save();
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    //sentry log
    captureException($e);
    return response()->json(["error"=>'true','message' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you confirm if you didn't reach any of these [limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en)?

Comment: @NaziA Yes over the course of a week we only created about 200 events all with internal (same domain) people. At most it was 4 people per event. And it was all on the same calendar